# Passive Verb + みる

Tags: nuances, verbs, passive-voice

A comment in one of my previous questions ([Why is a verb in the past (た形) contradicted with ～ていない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/why-is-a-verb-in-the-past-%e3%81%9f%e5%bd%a2-contradicted-with-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)) contained the following sentence (fragment?):

> 言われてみると不思議...。

I'm not entirely certain what this means but going from context, I'd guess maybe something along the lines of "It'd be odd if you tried to say it (like that)..."

I'm having difficulty understanding the changing voice (active/passive) in the verb 言われてみる. **Is this expression active or passive (or both for that matter)?**

In addition, how would the meanings of the following differ (if the second and third are valid of course):

> 1. 言われてみる
> 2. 言ってみられる
> 3. 言われてみられる

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「言{い}われてみると不思議{ふしぎ}...。」
>
> I'd guess maybe something along the lines of "***It'd be odd if you tried to say it (like that)...***"

Not really, it is not the speaker who said something here because 「言われる」 is passive voice.  **Another person told you something and you realize that it is indeed odd (even though you have never given the matter much thought before.)**

> I'm having difficulty understanding the changing voice (active/passive) in the verb 言われてみる. Is this expression active or passive (or both for that matter)?

Grammatically, the 「言われて」 part is passive and the 「みる」 part is active.  More strictly speaking, however, 「みる」 here is only a subsidiary verb; therefore, it is only active in name, so to speak.  The real verb here is 「言われる」, which is 100% passive.  Thus the expression 「言われてみる」 is basically passive voice.  At least, as I said above, it is not the speaker who said something.

> "Now that you mention it ..."

would be the usual translation.

Finally, regarding the three expressions you listed at the end, 「言ってみられる」 and 「言われてみられる」 (#2 and #3) do not make sense.