# What does "とらん" mean in this sentence?

Tags: syntax

> まだ梅雨にも入っとらんというのに…

I guess it just means "We're not even in the rainy season yet". However I can't figure out how "入る" becomes "入っとらん".

Answer (score 2):

[入]{はい}っとらん is a literary or dialectal way of saying [入]{はい}っていない. 
Here in your example it means "hasn't entered (into the rainy season)" → "(The rainy season) hasn't started (yet)".

[入]{はい}っ**と**らん is a colloquial contracted pronunciation of [入]{はい}っ**てお**らん.
～**てお**る (= て-form + subsidiary verb おる(居る)) contracts to ～**と**る in colloquial speech. For more on this kind of contraction, please see: [～ておく or ～とく for preparation (conjugation and nuance)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/9831).

[入]{はい}っておら**ん** is the negative form of 入っておる (= [入]{はい}っている in modern Japanese). The ん, or ぬ in its original form, is the literary negative auxiliary. For the usage and meaning of ～ておらん, please see: [How to use ておらん in lines like 食べておらん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53457/9831).