# What is the difference between 行きます and 行ってきます (ました、ません etc)?

Tags: grammar, syntax, politeness, て-form

When talking with a friend in Japanese, they said "行ってないです", they cannot explain why it's different from "行きません/でした".

As far as I'm aware, I'm not sure what the difference would be in terms of it meaning "I did not go" or "I have not been".

I understand that the 'te' form can modify a sentence to extend it or conjugate to てもいい etc, but in this context, what difference does it make between the two? There's been a couple of times like this I haven't understood the 'te' form fully. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Thanks very much,
Mat.

Comment: Related (行ってない/行っていません vs 行かなかった/行きませんでした): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42242/9831

Comment: You seem to be asking about "行って(い)ない and 行きませんでした" but the title of your question says "~~ between 行きます and 行って**き**ます", are you sure you meant to type 行って**き**ます not 行って**い**ます?

Answer (score 4):

Great question!

行ってくる、or more commonly 行ってきます is actually a really common phrase.  The most common usage is when individuals leave their home, but I have (on rare occasion) heard it used when people leave a gathering to go somewhere else. (i.e. party to work)  If you look at the translation on jisho.org, you will find the [following definition:](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B)  `I'm off; see you later​.`

According to [this answer,](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/22352) we find that 行ってきます has an implication of going, then coming back.  This is why you see it most commonly used when an individual leaves home for school/work.

行きます by contrast is simply translated as `I'm going.`

I want to make a note here:  行ってきます may seem to be related to the baseーて＋くる grammar structure.  Since the くる in 行ってきます is actually [implying *motion,*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/677/22352) it is **not** related.  Baseーて＋くる means: `came/got to be`  I personally understand it as `started to (verb),` but that translation has some issues.  If you're interested in learning about the Baseーて＋くる grammar, take a look at [this question,](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/22352) as well as this [website.](https://www.renshuu.org/grammar/82/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B)  I suggest that you take some time to study it when you get the chance.

Back on topic-- In short:

> 行ってきます
>
> **Literally:** I go and come back.
>
> **In natural English:** I'm off, see you later!

Finally:

> 行きます
>
> **Literally:** I'm going.
>
> **In natural English:** I'm going.