# Negative Past Tense

Tags: past, negation

I was reading a book and ran into the following sentence:

「 聞こえたか聞こえないかというくらいの音だ。」

It's supposed to mean something along the lines of "The sound was so quiet that I wasn't even sure if I heard it or not". Now my question is why isn't it 聞こえなかったか instead of 聞こえないか, what's the difference between the two, and how to tell when to use which?

Comment: Loosely related: [Why is a verb in the past (た形) contradicted with ～ていない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42242/why-is-a-verb-in-the-past-%e3%81%9f%e5%bd%a2-contradicted-with-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 日本語

> 「**聞こえたか聞こえないか**というくらいの音だ。」

「聞こえたか聞こえないか」は一種の慣用句であり、「聞こえたか聞こえなかったか」という意味を持った名詞とみなされています。文法的に見ると「過去形の肯定形＋現在形の過去形」ですので矛盾しているように見えますが、文法的に忠実である「聞こえたか聞こえなかったか」では、語呂が悪いのでこのようになっているものと思われます。
従って、文法的な分析をあまり進めても無駄だと思います。
割り切って慣用句として覚えましょう。

「言ったか言わないか」や「したかしないか」なども同じ性質を持った表現です。

この表現と似ていますが、「現在形の肯定形＋現在形の否定形」という形を持った表現として、「鳴るか鳴らない」「こぼれるかこぼれない」「出るか出ない」「（雨が）降るか降らない」などは、該当する動詞の動作がギリギリの状態であることを意味する別のタイプの慣用句です。この句の直後を上手に処理することで全体として名詞として扱うことで、次の用例で示すように時制の問題を <del>回避しているように見えます</del> 回避することができます。

次の用例を見ますと、上記の慣用句が、全体として過去形の文の中に使われていますが、この慣用句の部分を「現在形の動詞」とみなすと新たな疑問も出ますが、名詞として適切に処理しているとみるなら問題ないように思います。

- 出発のピストルが**鳴るか鳴らない**（**鳴るか鳴らない**かの）内に、選手は一斉にスタートした。
- 水はカップの淵｛ふち｝から**こぼれるかこぼれない**かというギリギリのところで留｛とど｝まっていた。
- 思い切って**でるかでない**かというところで悩んでいた。
- 雨が**降るか降らない**かという微妙な空模様で開催の有無を決めるのはむずかしかった。

Answer (score 3):

> 「 聞{き}こえたか聞こえないかというくらいの音{おと}だ。」

***Your*** translation is:

> "The sound was so quiet that ***I*** wasn't even sure if ***I*** heard it or not."

You are clearly thinking in English here. 「聞こえない」 ***can*** mean "I ***didn't*** hear it.", too.  In other words, **「聞こえない」 can mean the same as 「聞こえなかった」**.

If you asked a group of native Japanese-speakers a question like:

> 「今{いま}、そっちの方{ほう}から変{へん}な音{おと}、聞{き}こえなかった？」("Didn't you guys hear a strange sound from that direction just now?")

Quite a few would reply:

> 「聞{き}こえない。」 instead of 「聞こえなかった」.

That is real Japanese.  The fact that one is talking about the immediate past is clear from the context/situation even if one said 「聞こえない」.

Likewise, to the question 「昨日{きのう}バイト行{い}った？」, (far) more native speakers would reply 「行ってない。」 than 「行かなかった。」.

Another possible explanation:

You could think of 「聞こえたか聞こえないか」 as a set phrase.  The most often-used verb for this expression would be 「言{い}う」.  As discussed above, we often use 「**言った言わない**」 in he-said-she-said arguments.  Very few people would use 「言った言わなかった」.

The longer phrases using 「なかった」 is just not rhythmical.  With its long history as a spoken language, rhythm is still of utmost importance.  In other words, sound is important to us as, after all, sound is all you have in a spoken language.  Just look at our abundant use of onomatopoeias.  They rule our language.

Comment: "*You are clearly thinking in English here.*" -- as it is commonly known that the world population is divided between those thinking in Japanese and those thinking in English.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In your second example you put 「行ってない」, and not 「行かない」. Would 「行かない」 be wrong, or just not preferred? By the same token, would it be possible to say 「聞こえてない」 in the first example?

Comment: @Nikujin 行かない would be wrong because it means "I won't go".