# Is it natural to use 謙譲語 after being addressed with 尊敬語?

Tags: politeness, keigo, jlpt, listening

Can someone please explain why the answer to the following question is a and not b?

> 今朝の新聞、お読みになりましたか?
>
> - a. いいえ、 読んでいませんが
> - b. いえ、お読みしませんでした

Is weird to use 謙譲語 after someone has addressed you using 尊敬語? It the reason simply grammatical i.e.

I didn't read it vs I haven't read it.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82421/4875) answer your question?

Comment: Just curious, what level of the JLPT does this question belong to?

Comment: A is also weird for a different reason.

Comment: As aguijonazo pointed out, Sentence A doesn't make much sense unless the first question is in past tense. I have corrected it.

Comment: @jarmanso7 N3 Listening!